# Triggers and entry/exit actions for IsDefaulted and IsKeyboardFocused button storyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml

What's the proper way to trigger a defaulted/focused button glow effect on a custom button template in WPF? This would be similar in behavior to Windows 7's button glow and Windows 8/10's thick outline for focused and defaulted buttons.

(Note: vanilla WPF projects in Windows 7 do not exhibit the focused/defaulted button glow that is present in the rest of the operating system. Oh, Microsoft...)

I tried this:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsDefaulted" Value="False" />
        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsDefaultedStoryboard" />
    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="IsDefaultedStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource IsDefaultedStoryboard}" />
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

The behavior seems to be as expected, but it produces a lot of warnings -- one warning per button as they're loaded on-screen.

> System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control.; Action='Remove'; Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'; Storyboard.HashCode='16952812'; Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'; TargetElement='System.Windows.Controls.Button: Save'; TargetElement.HashCode='37829947'; TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Controls.Button'

My slightly more verbose solution still produces warnings -- although only upon losing focus -- and does not work as expected: when tabbing from the default button to another button, the default button keeps glowing.

```
<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="IsDefaultedStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource IsDefaultedStoryboard}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsDefaultedStoryboard" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="IsFocusedStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource IsDefaultedStoryboard}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsFocusedStoryboard" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

Maybe it's acceptable to use solution #1 and just ignore the warning, but I'd rather not. What's the better way to do this?

The storyboard is nothing exciting:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="IsDefaultedStoryboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="IsDefaulted" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="1" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.0" Value="0" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: In the first piece of code why are you removing on enter and using beginstoryboard on exit?

Comment: @GordonAllocman Because I'm essentially saying if you're neither focused nor defaulted, then you should have no storyboard. If you're focused or defaulted (i.e. the MultiTrigger no longer meets all of its conditions) then we should begin the glow storyboard. I think the logic is sound, but it's erroneous to remove storyboards that have not yet been created.

Comment: The first error (warning 6) is, as Gordon alludes; because it's attempting to remove a storyboard that hasn't even begun yet. I myself haven't really found a better way of keeping memory in check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up making an identical copy of the storyboard and applied it through two separate triggers, i.e.

```
<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="buttonStroke" Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="IsDefaultedStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource IsDefaultedStoryboard}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsDefaultedStoryboard" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="buttonStroke" Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="IsKeyboardFocusedStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource IsKeyboardFocusedStoryboard}" />
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsKeyboardFocusedStoryboard" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

I don't like the duplication, but it produces no warnings and works as expected.